# What are the differences between Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype) and Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the following codes, and start to wonder What are the differences between `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)` and `Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype`? since both Object.create(Shape.prototype) and Shape.prototype returns an Object.

```
//Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); //call super constructor.
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

Comment: Both are similar first one is standard of ES5 and second one is before ES5 standards.

Answer (score 3):

`Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;` is pointing Rectangle's prototype to the same object as Shape's prototype, meaning both prototypes are now the same object. So if you edit `Rectangle.prototype.method` it will also appear at `Shape.prototype.method`.

`Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);` is creating a **new object** that inherits Shape's prototype, and assigning to Rectangle's, meaning if you edit Rectangle's prototype from this point, it won't affect Shape's. But if you edit Shape's prototype, you will get the same properties in Rectangle by inheritance.

Have a play - https://jsfiddle.net/j8o10zfn/

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it some more, and you are right, so I removed the answer as it is a bad one. Thanks again Michael Geary

Comment: after `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype) ` is called, why edit the prototype of Shape will affect Rectangle??

Comment: @Blake - because of the prototypal inheritance model. That line means Rectangle's prototype is an object that inherits its properties from Shape's prototype. Have a look at this article - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain